# Cannot read property of undefined error on Angular RC3

Tags: javascript, angular, migration

i'm getting this error on the RC3, i'm trying to migrate my project gradually from release to another, i was having the same on the RC1 i've neglect it, i was assuming that it will be fixed once upgraded to RC3, here is my actual package.json content :

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {

    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^0.1.0",

    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/router":  "3.0.0-alpha.8",
    "@angular/router-deprecated":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.1",
    "es6-promise": "3.2.1",

    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.26",
    "zone.js": "0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings":"^0.8.1"
  }
}
```

and here is a screenshot of the error :

[image: ScreenShot]

for my app component ts :

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <navbar></navbar>

    <div class="container">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    `,
    directives:[NavBarComponent, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers:[PostService, HTTP_PROVIDERS]

})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  { 

  static home;

constructor(private _postService: PostService){
  } 

 ngOnInit(){

this._postService.getConf("conf/conf.json")

   .subscribe(res =>{
      var home = res;

      AppComponent.home = home.url;
 }

 );
     }
```

it's supposed to load my home page it's a simple welcome string :

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({

    template:`<br><h1>Bienvenue</h1>`
})
export class HomeComponent{

}
```

my routes :

```
import {provideRouter, RouterConfig} from '@angular/router';
import {HomeComponent} from './components/home.component';
import {ActionsComponent} from './components/actions.component';
import {TasksComponent} from './components/tasks.component';
import {DetailsComponent} from './components/details.component';
import {ActionFormComponent} from './forms/action-form.component';
import {TaskFormComponent} from './forms/task-form.component';
import {ActionViewFormComponent} from './forms/action-view-form.component';
import {TaskViewFormComponent} from './forms/task-view-form.component';


    export const appRoutes: RouterConfig = [

        {path:'', component:HomeComponent},

        {path:'actions',component:ActionsComponent},
        {path:'actions/:id',component:ActionFormComponent},
        {path:'actions/new', component:ActionFormComponent},
        {path:'actionview',component:ActionViewFormComponent},

        {path:'tasks',component:TasksComponent},
        {path:'tasks/:id',component:TaskFormComponent},
        {path:'tasks/new', component:TaskFormComponent},
        {path:'taskview',component:TaskViewFormComponent},

        {path:'*other',component:HomeComponent}

];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDER = provideRouter(appRoutes);
```

Comment: Please show your template.

Comment: sure, i've updated the question ..

Comment: the error is due to one of your html ... just show the html of the page when this error occurs in your console ?

Comment: what do you mean by showing it on the console ?, i was thinking the router will only show the default Home page and other pages will not cause any harm, can you please detail your answer ? show it how exactly on the console ?